# How to use file_get_contents() to read an uploaded image?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp, prepared-statement

I have a BLOB column in MySQL and want an uploaded image to be inserted. By reading some [reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-mysql-blob-data-type-to-store-images-with-php-on-ubuntu-18-04), I try to insert the image using `file_get_contents($path)`; but after repeated trials, the BLOB column remains **NULL** while the mime column is updated correctly. Can it be due to some file reading permission ? Is that `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES["profilePicture"]["tmp_name"]);` line having issues?

**The upload form**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?reqPage=profile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="profilePicture" class="form-label">Upload a photo for your profile</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="profilePicture" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**profile.php**

```
if ( isset($_FILES["profilePicture"]) && $_FILES["profilePicture"]["error"] == 0) { //if photo is uploaded without error
  $type = $_FILES["profilePicture"]["type"]; //browser provided mime
  $size = $_FILES["profilePicture"]["size"]; //size in bytes
  $filePath = $_FILES["profilePicture"]["tmp_name"]; //temporary path
  $image = file_get_contents($filePath);
  
  $sql = "UPDATE profiles SET profilePicture = ?, profilePictureMIME = ? WHERE 
  user = ?"; //for each user in profiles, profilePicture & MIME were initially null
  $param = [$image, $type, $user];
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($param);
}
```

**Columns in profiles table**

```
user VARCHAR(20),
profilePicture BLOB,
profilePictureMIME VARCHAR(30),
```

Comment: You cannot store an image inside a database, you either convert it to a blob or you upload it to your server and then store the path to it

Comment: @Jaquarh the former is what I am trying to do, it seems file_get_contents() result can be stored in a BLOB column from my reading.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($image)` ?